# Nested while Loops Python

Tags: python, loops

I am quite new to python. I have this problem where I should write a program that calculates a customer monthly bill. It should ask which package the customer has purchased (package A, B or C), what month (in terms of numeric), and how many hours were used. It should then display the total amount due.

Also the number of hours should not exceeds the total number of hours per month (assuming every month has 30 days = 720 hours).

The specifications are:

```
Package A: For Php200.00 per month, 10 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are Php15.00 per hour.
Package B: For Php500.00 per month, 20 hours of access are provided. Additional hours are Php10.00 per hour.
Package C: For Php900.00 per month, unlimited access is provided.
```

My code is working as intended so far. But I also want to keep looping the 2nd and 3rd Input ("month" and "hours")  as long as the input is wrong and then proceed to the next.

here is my code:

```
price_A = 200.00
price_B = 500.00
price_C = 900.00

Package = ""
package = False

while Package not in ("A", "a", "B", "b", "C", "c"):
    Package = input("Enter package: ")
    package = True
    if Package in ("A", "a"):
        month = int(input("Enter month: "))
        if int(float(month)) >= 1 and int(float(month)) <= 12:
            hours = int(input("Enter hours: "))
            if int(float(hours)) >= 0 and int(float(hours)) <= 720:
                if int(float(hours)) >= 0 and int(float(hours)) <= 10:
                    total = price_A
                    f_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
                    print("Total amount due is Php " + f_total)
                elif int(float(hours)) >= 10:
                    total = ((hours - 10) * 15.00) + price_A
                    f_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
                    print("Total amount due is Php " + f_total)
            else:
                print("Invalid Hours!")
        else:
            print("Invalid Month!")
    elif Package in ("B", "b"):
        month = int(input("Enter month: "))
        if int(float(month)) >= 1 and int(float(month)) <= 12:
            hours = int(input("Enter hours: "))
            if int(float(hours)) >= 0 and int(float(hours)) <= 720:
                if int(float(hours)) >= 0 and int(float(hours)) <= 20:
                    total = price_B
                    f_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
                    print("Total amount due is Php " + f_total)
                elif int(float(hours)) >= 20:
                    total = ((hours - 10) * 10.00) + price_B
                    f_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
                    print("Total amount due is Php " + f_total)
            else:
                print("Invalid Hours!")
        else:
            print("Invalid Month!")
    elif Package in ("C", "c"):
        f_total = "{:.2f}".format(price_C)
        print("Total amount due is Php " + str(f_total))

    else:
        print("Invalid Package!")
```

I still do not know where should I put the while loop for the 2nd and 3rd Inputs.

Comment: **Tips for future:** Having so many nested conditional (`if` / `elif` / `else`) statements is going to make your code very difficult to keep track of. Additionally, its always a good idea to use the `lower()` or `upper()` functions to [standardize user inputs](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-lowercase-how-to-use-the-string-lower-function/). These kinds of simplifications should always be done before putting things in nested loops (it'll save you a lot of headaches).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one hope it's helpful

```
price_A = 200.00
price_B = 500.00
price_C = 900.00


while True:
    Package = input("Enter package: ")
    if Package.lower() == "a":
        month = int(input("Enter month: "))
        if int(float(month)) >= 1 and int(float(month)) <= 12:
            hours = int(input("Enter hours: "))
            if int(float(hours)) >= 0 and int(float(hours)) <= 720:
                if int(float(hours)) >= 0 and int(float(hours)) <= 10:
                    total = price_A
                    f_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
                    print("Total amount due is Php " + f_total)
                elif int(float(hours)) >= 10:
                    total = ((hours - 10) * 15.00) + price_A
                    f_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
                    print("Total amount due is Php " + f_total)
            else:
                print("Invalid Hours!")
        else:
            print("Invalid Month!")
    elif Package.lower() == "b":
        month = int(input("Enter month: "))
        if int(float(month)) >= 1 and int(float(month)) <= 12:
            hours = int(input("Enter hours: "))
            if int(float(hours)) >= 0 and int(float(hours)) <= 720:
                if int(float(hours)) >= 0 and int(float(hours)) <= 20:
                    total = price_B
                    f_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
                    print("Total amount due is Php " + f_total)
                elif int(float(hours)) >= 20:
                    total = ((hours - 10) * 10.00) + price_B
                    f_total = "{:.2f}".format(total)
                    print("Total amount due is Php " + f_total)
            else:
                print("Invalid Hours!")
        else:
            print("Invalid Month!")
    elif Package.lower() == "c":
        f_total = "{:.2f}".format(price_C)
        print("Total amount due is Php " + str(f_total))

    else:
        print("Invalid Package!")
    next_package = input("Continue? : Y/N ")
    if next_package.lower() == 'n':
        break
```